# How to correctly put function in object Javascript by method?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to make an object by function method because of lots of object I have to put in. I do step by step from instruction but this method do not work for me. I think the main problem is in function in function. I want to have all object have their its value of the second function so I name "A", "B", "C", "D" fields.

```
function pol () {
    this.name = name;
    this.moc = moc; 
    this.square = square;
    this.A = A;
    this.B = B;
    this.C = C;
    this.D = D;
    this.price = function(){
        if(wynik1 >18000){ return A;}
        if(wynik1 >10000){ return B;}
        if(wynik1 >5000){ return C;}
        if(wynik1>3000){ return D;}
    })();    
}

var Bingo = new pol ("Psyche", 370, 1.7, 4000, 4200, 4600, 5000); 
var Ringo = new pol("Psyche Myche", 370, 1.7, 4000, 4200, 4600, 5000); 
var Zingo = new pol("Psyche Ryche", 370, 1.7, 4000, 4200, 4600, 5000); 

var moc = pol.Ringo.moc
var pow = pol.Ringo.square
var prices = pol.Ringo.price();
```

I have problem in this step but my next step is

```
var moc = function (){
    if(k =="A"){return: pol.Ringo.moc}
    if(k =="A"){return: pol.Bingo.moc}
    if(k =="A"){return: pol.Zingo.moc}
}();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code. Go back to the instructions and look at the function definition. Your `function pol() {...}` does not assign any parameters. I'm pretty sure you want that to look like this: `function pol(name, moc, square, A, B,  C, D) {...}`. I think the same issue exists with the method `this.price` - that one appears to need to accept `wynik1` as a parameter. As for the last part, you'll need to get the first part to work before you can accomplish the second part.

Comment: Also you've immediately invoked the function and assigned the result to `.price`, instead of assigning the function to create a method.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you run:

```
var Ringo = new pol("Psyche Myche", 370, 1.7, 4000, 4200, 4600, 5000);
```

you have added inputs into this `pol` constructor. By that logic, you also need to have parameters defined in the `pol` constructor like:

```
function pol (name, moc, square, A, B, C, D) {...}
```

As a side note, be careful about the line: `var prices = pol.Ringo.price();` You define `this.price` as:

```
function(){
    if(wynik1 >18000){ return A;}
    if(wynik1 >10000){ return B;}
    if(wynik1 >5000){ return C;}
    if(wynik1>3000){ return D;}
})();
```

Those final parentheses are making this function return a *value* instead of setting `this.price` to a *function*. You'll notice I copied the syntax error (the single parenthesis after the close of the function) because that decides whether this will return a value or not. If you remove that one parenthesis, you also need to remove the `()` as well. Decide if `this.price` is supposed to be a function or a value. Based on the fact that you tried `pol.Ringo.price()`, you probably want it to instead be a *function* like (also note the added parameter of `wynik1` (assuming you then call `Ringo.price(some number)`):

```
this.price = function(wynik1) {
    if(wynik1 >18000){ return A;}
    if(wynik1 >10000){ return B;}
    if(wynik1 >5000){ return C;}
    if(wynik1>3000){ return D;}
}; // no additional parentheses
```

The `this.price` function should also not be using `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. It should instead be accessing the *specific* values that are connected with a *specific* `pol` constructor: `this.A`, `this.B`, `this.C`, and `this.D`.

The final note is that the use of `pol.Ringo.moc` (or any of your other parameters will not work. Since `pol` is a constructor, when you create a `new pol`, there is no connection to the *variable* `pol`. `Ringo` will now point to different storage that has all of the information copied over, then set based on the parameters you get to `new pol(...)`. You instead can access any of your new `pol` constructs just by using the variable name and doing something like:

```
var moc = Ringo.moc
var pow = Ringo.square
var prices = Ringo.price();
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, with your help, I managed to fix it but I don't understand why it works.

```
var Ringo = new pol("Psyche", 370, 1.7, 4000, 4200, 4600, 5000); 
var prices = Ringo.price(4000, 4200, 4600, 5000);
```

in `Ringo.price();` I can put any numbers and it works just like 1, 2, 3, 4 but if I put "a", "b", "c', "d" or empty do not. Why i can not just put there noting.